# Is there a Mysql "in" for set statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a mysql command to check if a column value is in a set?
Something along the lines of the python code:

```
column_value in ['a', 'b', 'cde']
```

I know you can simulate that with a whole bunch of ORs, but I thought perhaps if such a statement exists MySQL would be able to optimize the checks more heavily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The SQL standard has the `IN (...)` syntax.

```
where column_value in ('a', 'b', 'cde')
```

You were remarkably close: Just change square brackets for round ones.

Note: This syntax works for constant values, but you can use it with derived values like this:

```
where column_value in (select some_column from some_table where some_condition)
```

Comment: Not sure how I missed this :P

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

```
WHERE column_name IN ('a', 'b', 'cde')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE column_value IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
```